# How to store any value when event is raised?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to measure the time between when I unplug my laptop and battery level reaching 10%.

I've managed to wire up the event so far but I can't figure out where I can store the values of time so that I can do subtraction later.

```
public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SystemInformation.PowerStatus.PowerLineStatus.ToString() == "Offline")
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a member variable to store the information?

Comment: I tried to create string variable in Main method but how can I modify that string when event is raised? I was going to store the time in 2 strings that way but I can't change them because it does not exist in current context when trying to change them inside event handler.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would use a member variable to store the DateTimes that you want to observe.

```
public class Program
{

private static DateTime startTime;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SystemInformation.PowerStatus.PowerLineStatus.ToString() == "Offline")
    {
        this.startTime = DateTime.Now();
    }
}
}
```

Using DateTimes also depends on what level of accuracy you want.  If you are talking about measuring anything under a few seconds I would recommend using a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instead.